# Error in getting Dropbox file (mp4) link using exisiting Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropbox

This is a continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415929/get-publicly-accessible-link-of-drop-box-file-using-google-apps-script/77416233#77416233). I am using the following script to get the publicly accessible file link:

```
function listDropBoxFiles() {

  const accessToken = "sl.BpQiX-y5a6GhuZ9_QmHnCeT3u6OMoVRiKrPDOe_YzOVtDUCUUlEYrMd92faMVlJQr28d3md5YKvN4au1B6HIdEeRug0LdL66Qo1UGlXmNx3RiMNZDcZqPVZvWLbJEroQxurJye23YxjGFCvMPnJUbFI";
  var subfolderName = "";
 
  const path = "/Master Folder";

  let url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder";
  let has_more = false;
  var count = 0;
  const option = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path, limit: 2000, recursive: true })
  };
  let values = [];
  var fileDetails = [];
  do {
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
    let obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());

    values = [...values, ...obj.entries];
    has_more = obj.has_more;

    if (has_more) {
      url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder/continue";
      option.payload = JSON.stringify({ cursor: obj.cursor });
    }
  } while (has_more);
  
   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    
      var entry = values[i];
      
    if (entry['.tag'] === 'file') {
      
       var match = entry.path_display.split('/');
       subfolderName = match[match.length - 2];   
      
       var fileUrl = getFileUrl(accessToken,entry.id)

       fileDetails.push([subfolderName,entry.name,fileUrl,Utilities.formatDate(new Date(entry.client_modified), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'),Utilities.formatDate(new Date(entry.server_modified), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a')])
     
    }
  }
    
      if(fileDetails.length>0){
         detailSheet.getRange(detailSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,fileDetails.length,fileDetails[0].length).setValues(fileDetails);
      }
}



function getFileUrl(accessToken, fileId) {
  const url1 = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/list_shared_links";
  const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path: fileId })
  });
  const obj1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());
  if (obj1.links.length > 0) {
    return obj1.links[0].url;
  }
  const url2 = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings";
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path: fileId, settings: { access: "viewer", allow_download: true, audience: "public", requested_visibility: "public" } })
  });
  const obj2 = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
  const sharedLink = obj2.url;
  return sharedLink;
}
```

However, sometimes it works other times it does not, the issue is it gives the folder link of the files instead of actual links to the files. What I mean by that is it gives the folder/subfolder links where these files are saved instead of the files' links. For example, in my Master folder, there are 3 files and the script gives the **following output:**

```
1. Live Video.mp4   
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/mhiwyb9u7kjrhtw05rsdr/h?rlkey=6mj30yhcyahu9ypjddx2uz962&dl=0

2. Custom Data Entry Form.jpg   
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/mhiwyb9u7kjrhtw05rsdr/h?rlkey=6mj30yhcyahu9ypjddx2uz962&dl=0

3.Format Number.txt 
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/io1xsqja0y44n7wilphp0/h?rlkey=jhuvdusw204k71nnl9axhbtnr&dl=0
```

Here you can see that when you click on these links, they open the folders that contain these files instead of opening these files. The data for a file named `1. Live Video.mp4` looks like this:

```
{ '.tag': 'file',
  name: 'Live Video.mp4',
  path_lower: '/master folder/live video.mp4',
  path_display: '/Master Folder/Live Video.mp4',
  id: 'id:c0kbDV6PiUcAAAAAAAAAGw',
  client_modified: '2023-11-05T07:25:40Z',
  server_modified: '2023-11-05T07:31:28Z',
  rev: '0160962b9c6509b00000002277bc0d0',
  size: 348179266,
  is_downloadable: true,
  content_hash: '41247114de3e285fb84fefd961801a73a7072cba9d043bd123e0e73ea5707271' }
```

if you plug `'id:c0kbDV6PiUcAAAAAAAAAGw'` into `getFileUrl()` from the above response, it gets the folder link instead of the file link, below is the response `(obj1/obj2)`:

```
{ links: 
   [ { '.tag': 'folder',
       url: 'https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/mhiwyb9u7kjrhtw05rsdr/h?rlkey=6mj30yhcyahu9ypjddx2uz962&dl=0',
       id: 'id:c0kbDV6PiUcAAAAAAAAAGg',
       name: 'Master Folder',
       path_lower: '/master folder',
       link_permissions: [Object] } ],
  has_more: false }
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your script, I think that only the files are retrieved by `if (entry['.tag'] === 'file') {,,,}`. But, you say `it gives the folder link of the files instead of actual links to the files.`. In this case, it is required to confirm your actual situation. In your situation, even when `entry['.tag'] === 'file'` is true, is the folder retrieved? In order to confirm this, can you provide the value of `entry` of `1. Live Video.mp4`? By the way, when I tested your showing script, only files were retrieved. The result value didn't include the folders.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the script outputs `entry.id` for the `1. Live Video.mp4` : `id:c0kbDV6PiUcAAAAAAAAAGw`. When you get url using this, it opens folder and not the file. I have modified (response for this file added) my question as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your added information, it seems that the value of `.tag` is `'.tag': 'file'`. So, I cannot understand the reason that the folder is retrieved. And, when I tested your showing script, unfortunately, no folders were retrieved. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? And, as additional information, can you provide the value of `obj1` or `obj2` for `Live Video.mp4`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation using your showing script. I apologize for my poor skill. When I can correctly replicate your situation, I believe that I can propose a modified script. So, I would like to try to correctly replicate your situation. When you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I have added `obj1/obj2` for `Live Video.mp4` in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I found the issue in the following function:

```
function getFileUrl(accessToken, fileId) {
  const url1 = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/list_shared_links";
  const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path: fileId })
  });
  const obj1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());
  if (obj1.links.length > 0) {
    return obj1.links[0].url;
  }
  const url2 = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings";
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path: fileId, settings: { access: "viewer", allow_download: true, audience: "public", requested_visibility: "public" } })
  });
  const obj2 = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
  const sharedLink = obj2.url;
  return sharedLink;
}
```

In the above function, the `if` condition checks if there is already any link, but the issue is it also considers subfolders' links, if there are subfolders, it does not look for the file link, it just gets the subfolder link and the condition is considered to be true.

So from changing this:

```
 if (obj1.links.length > 0) {
        return obj1.links[0].url;
      }
```

to this solved the **issue**:

```
 if (obj1.links[0]['.tag'] === 'file') {
    return obj1.links[0].url;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation for /2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links):

> If a non-empty path is given, returns a list of all shared links that allow access to the given path - direct links to the given path and links to parent folders of the given path. Links to parent folders can be suppressed by setting direct_only to true.

So if you want to prevent the API from returning shared links for the parent folders in addition to the file, set `direct_only: true` on your /2/sharing/list_shared_links call.